# How to receive Event Hubs messages from a specific partition in Azure Functions

Tags: azure

I want to receive Event Hubs messages from a specific partition into my Azure Function. How to achieve this? I am able to do such operation while running on locally using a NodeJs script. However, While using Azure Functions trigger for Event Hubs, I do not see such option where I can mention the **partionId** so that my function receives messages from a specific partition only.

Use case: My 2 partition will receive different types of data. As a result, the business logics are different. Therefore, I don't want to mess one Azure function with multiple business logics.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions doesn't support consuming from a specific partition.

Your options are:

1. Receive all events from all partitions and process only events those from your specific partition while ignoring the rest.
2. Instead of creating an affinity between event type and partition, create affinity between event type and eventhub. This way each event type will have its own eventhub and you won't need to worry about consuming from a specific partition.